# EF Core 3.0 stored procedure: exec the procedure with params but not from models

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I use .NET Core 3 with EF Core and SQL Server 2017 Express.

I want to call a stored procedure to process my business. It has some parameters and the result will be returned in JSON format.

I have searched for a solution, but I can not find the way to do it.

I saw a lot of examples:

```
var user = "johndoe";

var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

But, in my business, I think I need example like the old ways, input parameter and get result is object or JSON.

```
DynamicParameters param = new DynamicParameters();

                param.Add("p_status", status);
                if (pMasGlobal != null)
            {
                param.Add("p_COMPANY_ID", pMasGlobal.COMPANY_ID);
                param.Add("p_Name", pMasGlobal.Name);
                param.Add("p_DEL_YN", pMasGlobal.DEL_YN);
            }

            param.Add("@p_outValue", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

            conn.Open();
            iResult = conn.Execute("sp_zm_mas_global", param, null, null, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            if (status == "INSERT")
            {
                int outValue = param.Get<int>("@p_outValue");
            }
```

Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: please, help me to call store. I research a lot of internet, but I really don't know why, call sp very hard with .net Core 3.

Comment: hi, I need help, please